# Flutter session expired after re open the app

Tags: android, flutter, api, authentication

i have an application created under flutter
my problem is that the session is expired after re open the application in the next hour
for exemple i close the app and after 1 hour i open the app but the session is expired and i can go to home page without login but the data not loaded

this is my api file in flutter section

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Network {
  final String _url = 'https://smartcollecte.ma/public/api';
  final String _imgUrl = 'https://smartcollecte.ma/public/uploads/';

  getImage() {
    return _imgUrl;
  }

  //if you are using android studio emulator, change localhost to 10.0.2.2
  var token;

  _setHeaders() async {
    var data = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      //'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'

    };
    String token = await _getToken();
    if (token != '')
    {
      data['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
      print(token);

    }
    return data;
  }

  authData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
    return await http.post(Uri.parse(fullUrl),
        body: jsonEncode(data), headers: await _setHeaders());
  }

  logAuthData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
    return await http.post(Uri.parse(fullUrl),
        body: jsonEncode(data), headers: await _setHeaders());
  }

  getData(apiUrl) async {
    String fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
    return await http.get(Uri.parse(fullUrl), headers: await _setHeaders());
  }

  // _getTokenData() async {
  //   SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //   String? token_ = localStorage.getString('token');
  //   return token != null ? token : '';
  // }

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? token = localStorage.getString('token');
    return '?token=$token';
  }

  getArticles(apiUrl) async {}
  getPublicData(apiUrl) async {}
}
```